# Ionic 5: How do you get the input value from another page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

First of all I just want to mention that I am a noob and pretty new to all of this, so please bear with me.

So, currently I am working on a project, which kind of acts like a calculator. I am using the tabs template and on the first tab there is a number given. Let's say 1. On another tab the user has to give a number input and the value of this input should be added to the number 1 from the first tab. I already have an idea, which works, but I was told that it's not usual, as I directly approach the DOM instead of using Angular. However, I don't know how I could use Angular in this project.

My approach:

Tab1 HTML:

```
<p id="amount">0</p>
```

Tab2 HTML:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="adding"></ion-input>
<ion-button (click)="AddToNumber()">Add</ion-button>
```

Tab2 TS:

```
adding: number

AddToNumber() {
    let currentNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('amount').innerHTML)
    let sum = String(add += this.number)
    document.getElementbyId('amount).innerHTML = sum
}
```

Comment: Use angular service, store ur data there and then take it back from there when u need

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you can simply use the angular interpolator operator `{{}}`.

In your example, try this:

Tab1 HTML:

```
<p>{{sum}}</p>
```

Tab2.ts:

```
adding: number;
sum = 0;

AddToNumber() { 
    this.sum += this.number;
    
}
```

For detailed info, check this out: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/interpolation-in-angular/

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but I am not quite sure if your solution works, as the variable "sum" belongs to Tab2. Can you still put the variable into the interpolator operator in Tab1 even though it's from another page? Unfortunately when I tried it the paragraph didn't show anything. But still, thank you for answering.